# The difference between browser cache and ServiceWorker cache

Tags: caching, service-worker, browser-cache

I do not understand the difference between browser cache and ServiceWorker cache.

For example, in browser cache, set the expiration cache for all resources. In this way, the HEAD should not verify within the time limit. In other words, you should be able to acquire resources in an offline state because you do not query the server.

On the other hand, if you set cache priority in ServiceWorker, you can acquire resources in the offline state after the second time.

***"Both browser cache and ServiceWorker cache can get resources in the offline state"***

Is it good to understand that?

Answer (score 0):

I think by "browser cache" you mean the http cache.  This is an opportunistic cache of responses across the entire browser.  (Mostly, that is.  In some browsers its isolated by the top level tab origin.)  The browser can evict responses from http cache at any time.  It makes no guarantees that data will be present in the http cache at any time.  Generally, though, it uses an LRU-based heuristic to age older unused data out.  Sites can influence what is stored in http cache using cache-control headers.

In contrast, the Cache API used in service workers is more like IndexedDB.  While it stores responses just like http cache it differs in that the site is fully in control.  There is an explicitly API for storing and retrieving data.  The browser guarantees Cache API data will not be deleted unless the site does it themselves or the entire origin is evicted via the quota mechanism.  The Cache API is also much more precisely specified in terms of its behavior compared to http cache.  The only way to use the Cache API data during loading, though, is via a `ServiceWorker` that matches a request using Cache API and then returns the `Response` to the `FetchEvent.respondWith()`.

Note a `ServiceWorker` can end up interacting with both of these systems.  It can explicitly use the Cache API.  It can also pull from http cache when it calls `fetch()`.